# What's the point of std::remove_reference

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, reference, c++14

Let me dive in C++14 generic lambdas with:

```
#include <iostream>

// g++ -std=c++14 

template<typename T>
T incr(T v)
{
    return v + 1;
}


int main()
{
    float f = 2.0;
    int i = 3;

    auto selfincr = [] (auto & value)
        {
            value = incr<std::remove_reference<decltype(value)>>(value);    // A
            value = incr<decltype(value)>(value);                           // B
        };


    selfincr(f);
    selfincr(i);

    std::cout << "f " << f << ", i " << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since line `// B` causes a

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘T&’ from an rvalue of type ‘T’

My immediate guessing has been the removal of the reference, so I added line `// A`. But this yield a

> no matching function for call to ‘incr(T&)’

So how could I remove that reference ?

Comment: Like most type traits, you are actually interested in one of the trait's members. Try `typename std::remove_reference<decltype(value)>::type` or `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(value)>`.

Comment: This is orthogonal to your question, but does a call to `incr` not deduce the type automatically?

Comment: or "fix" `incr` to not return reference of temporary: `template<typename T>
auto incr(T v)
{
    return v + 1;
}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So how could I remove that reference ?

`incr<std::remove_reference<decltype(value)>>(value)`, you're specifying [`std::remove_reference<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) as the template parameter, but not the type referred by `T` (i.e. `decltype(value)`). What you want should be

```
value = incr<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(value)>::type>(value);    // A
//           ~~~~~~~~                                       ~~~~~~
```

And since C++14 you could make it simpler:

```
value = incr<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(value)>>(value);    // A
//                                ~~
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/auGp9eSq3ImR7tCK)

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
value = incr<std::remove_reference<decltype(value)>>(value);    // A
```

doesn't work due to what [songyuanyao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50158895/2069064) explained.

---

This:

```
value = incr<decltype(value)>(value);                           // B
```

doesn't work becuase `decltype(value)` is a reference type and you're trying to instantiate:

```
float& incr(float& v) { return v + 1; }
int& incr(int& v) { return v + 1; }
```

You can't bind those expressions to non-const lvalue references, hence the compile error.

---

The simplest solution is to just let template deduction do its thing:

```
value = incr(value); // C
```

That will call `incr<int>` and `incr<float>` as desired.